# Inkscape Scripting Transform Functions

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to use inkscape from the command line ([reference page](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html)). Their examples work, however, when I try to use transform-, specifically transform-grow and transform-translate I get the errors:

`parse_actions: could not find action for: “transform-grow”`
and
`parse_actions: could not find action for: “transform-translate”`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Inkscape version: 1.2.1 (2022-07-14)

Example action: inkscape --query-id=path1234 input.svg --actions=“transform-grow” --export-filename output.svg

Comment: Please edit your question to: add Inkscape version, and a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

> transform-scale

To see all possible action, type on the command line:
`inkscape --action-list`

Not sure if your example would work. I think the input file must be the last argument in the command line. It is recommended to use the parameter
`--batch-process` before the action list.